# Compiler variance: type of `this` when value-captured in mutable lambda defined in a const member function

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, clang, language-lawyer

The following program

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
  void f() const {
    (void)[*this]() mutable {
      static_assert(
          std::is_same_v<decltype(this), S *>);  // Fails with GCC & MSVC
      static_assert(
          std::is_same_v<decltype(this), const S *>);  // Fails with Clang
      (void)this;
    }
    ();
  }
};

int main() {}
```

contains a *mutable* lambda which captures `*this` by value (`[*this]`), and which does so in a *const*-qualified member function. The program is rejected by GCC due to `#1`, and rejected by Clang due to `#2` (and conversely accepted):

- GCC<sup>(1)</sup> and MSVC thinks `decltype(this)` is `const S *`
- Clang<sup>(1)</sup> thinks `decltype(this)` is `S *`

<sup>(1) Various compiler versions for C++17 and C++20</sup>

[DEMO](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4j9b8q6fq).

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around, that is, Clang thinks `decltype(this)` is `S*`?

Comment: @bogdan Yes I mixed them up, thanks. Corrected (likewise in my self-answer).

Answer (score 3):

#### GCC/MSVC are correct, Clang is reasonable but incorrect

[[expr.prim.lambda.closure[/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#12):

> The lambda-expression's compound-statement yields the function-body ([dcl.fct.def]) of the function call operator, **but for purposes of** name lookup, **determining the type and value of `this`** and transforming id-expressions referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using (*this) ([class.mfct.non-static]), the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression.

means [[class.this]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.this#1) applies:

> In the body of a non-static ([class.mfct]) member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue whose value is a pointer to the object for which the function is called. **The type of `this` in a member function whose type has a cv-qualifier-seq cv and whose class is X is “pointer to cv X”.**

GCC/MSVC and Clang may be applying [class.this]/1, particularly regarding the cv-qualifier of the member function, to either of

1. the cv-qualification of the member function in which the lambda is defined, `S::f()` in OP's example, which is const-qualified, or
2. the cv-qualification of the function call operator of the lambda, which is not const-qualified (due to `mutable`),

particularly GCC and MSVC choosing interpretation 1, whereas Clang chooses interpretation 2. We may note that if we slightly tweak OP's example to capture the lambda by capturing `*this` by reference, `[this]`, [all compilers agree](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5Wsq1j6b6) that `decltype(this)` in the lambda is `const S *` (which makes sense).

Based on the standard passages above, particularly [expr.prim.lambda.closure]/12, I would argue that Clang is wrong to let `this` be non-const-qualified when `*this` has been value-captured by a mutable lambda from within a `const`-qualified method. Even if it could make *sense* to base constness for a value-copied `*this` on the constness of the function call operator of the lambda's closure type, the standard does not support it.

We may finally note that we see the same behaviour if using overload resolution instead of `decltype` (i.e. comparing `this` in our outside of an unevaluated context), namely GCC and MSVC preserving constness of the copy-captured `*this`, where Clang does not.

**Bug reports?**

I have not been able to find any Clang bug reports for this, and have hence filed:

- [Bug 51524 - '*this' captured by copy does not preserve constness of '*this' in mutable lambda](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51524)

Comment: I think it makes sense that capturing `*this` by copy should be consistent with capturing any other local entity by copy. That is, capturing `const int x` by copy in a mutable lambda results in a const member in the closure object; `*this` should behave in the same way. (And I agree with your interpretation of the wording.)

Comment: However, for completeness, we should [note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda.capture#note-7) that `decltype` is an unevaluated context, so `this` in there refers to the original entity, not the copy in the closure type, so the results should be the same anyway regardless of whether `*this` is captured by copy or by reference. (Yeah, `this` is not an *id-expression*, so the note doesn't strictly apply, but the sentence below only says that the expression is transformed if it odr-uses `*this`.)

Comment: @bogdan I agree, thanks. We see the same behaviour also without `decltype`, e.g. using overload resolution to query constness.